# Tuple to datetime object

Tags: python, time

I have a tuple that looks like this

```
(datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 25, 14, 8, 56),)
```

And I want to convert it to a datetime object, in python?

How can I do this?

I have tried

```
import datetime

time = datetime.datetime(my_tuple)
```

Bu that didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just get the first element of the tuple, which is a `datetime` object already.

```
time = my_tuple[0]
```

Comment: For me, the first item of a date tuple is only the year

Comment: @CarsonEvans - Then this question and its answer are not applicable to the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect the OP is asking how to unpack the tuple into arguments.

```
from datetime import datetime

#Typical datetime call
my_date1 = datetime(2022,1,28)

#If year,month, and day are in a tuple
my_tuple = (2022,1,28)
my_date2 = datetime(*my_tuple) #Unpacks the tuple into datetime arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

see link

https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-datetime-time-conversions/

```
from datetime import datetime

start_date = datetime(2019,8,2)

expiry_dates = datetime(2019,10,2)
```